# Getting info on files that were shared between dates

Tags: query, files, shared-activities

I'm fairly new to **Salesforce API**, I'm trying to get information on files that were **shared** **between dates**. I would like to know how to retrieve this info using **REST API**. Is it even possible to query this data?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the community! What have you tried so far? What Is your use case? I'm afraid as it is now your question is entirely too broad and will likely be closed.

Comment: I'm trying to audit sharing logs on Salesforce, I want to get information each time the file is shared between users. So far I'm tried to query the SQL salesforce DB but with no success. @gNerb

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/228957/edit) your question instead of posting information to the comments. Make sure to include an example of what you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing of Content (Lightning Files) is mediated by the [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) object.

There are some roadblocks built into the Content functionality to achieving what you are aiming at through the API/SOQL alone, including:

> Users (including users with the “View All Data” permission) can only query files they have access to, including:
>
> All Salesforce CRM Content files in libraries they're a member of and in their personal library, regardless of library permissions (API version 17.0 and later).
>
> All Salesforce Files they own, posted on their profile, posted on groups they can see, and shared directly with them (API version 21.0 and later).

You also are highly limited in terms of what queries you can execute against the object:

> You can't run a query without filters against `ContentDocumentLink`. [...] A SOQL query must filter on one of `Id`, `ContentDocumentId`, or `LinkedEntityId`.

Hence, you cannot, for example, run a query like

```
SELECT Id, SystemModStamp FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE SystemModStamp = TODAY
```

You must query against specific linked records or specific Content files if you do not already have the Ids of the link objects, and you're limited in what Content files you can see by the system.

You might find better success than API-based querying if you add a trigger (`ContentDocumentLink` supports before/after insert/update/delete triggers) to build a shadow audit table in an object that you *can* query externally.

If you wanted to pursue that route, you'd add a custom object (say `ContentDocumentLink_Audit__c`). Add fields to track the values from `ContentDocumentLink` that you're interested in, potentially including details of the file being shared and where or to whom the share is taking place. (You would need to perform one or more additional queries to obtain those details based upon the link records `ContentDocumentId` and `LinkedEntityId`; the latter will be trickier because it is a polymorphic lookup, but at minimum you can distinguish between direct shares to users and to files by looking at the Id value).

Then, implement a trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` `after insert` and construct `ContentDocumentLink_Audit__c` records that represent the new share being establish. Insert those records to form a part of your permanent audit trail, and you can then query from your external solution over the API against `ContentDocumentLink_Audit__c`.

If you need your shadow table to also record updates and deletions of sharing, you can extend that trigger to also run `after update` and `after delete`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you maybe provide some more information on how would you advise to implement it programmatically? Or maybe point to some good links on this topic?

Comment: I've expanded my answer on this subject but I don't think I can get into much more detail based on what you've shared about your objective. You're welcome to ask more specific questions as you dive into the implementation.